# Similarity and Congruence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $S \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ for odd prime $p$. Show that $S=Z^TZ$ for some $Z \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ if and only if $S^{-T}S=I$.

It can be easily shown that $S=Z^TZ$ implies $S^{-T}S=I$, but for the converse, I am not sure if $S=S^T$ would imply that $S=Z^TZ$ for some $Z$ considering that the entries of $S$ are from $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Thank you so much!

Comment: In fact, it normal would not be the case that $S = S^T$ implies that $S = Z^TZ$ for some $Z$ (i.e. if the entries are from $\Bbb R$). If it holds in this case, then it is *because* the entries are from $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: Note that this does **not** hold for $n=1$; it is not true that every element of $\Bbb Z_p$ is a quadratic residue. For instance, $S = -1 \in GL_1(\Bbb Z_3)$ cannot be written in the form $S = Z^TZ$.

Comment: Could you please provide some more context? In particular, where did you encounter this question?